# winsock2 sending and receiving

Tags: c++, send, winsock2

I've search forum but could not find proper answer for my problem. I'm going to make little logg-in procedure so I want send data being in edit box as login, then send data being in second edit box as password.

```
int ldata2 = send(Socket, buffs, len, 0);//send login via socket
//send pass via socket
int passData = send(Socket, buffPass, lenPass, 0);
```

Above instructions are handled by client off course. On server-side when i call recv i.e this way:

```
int dt = recv(SocketM[i], 
                                        strings,
                                        128,
                                        0);

                        int errsock = WSAGetLastError();
                        if(errsock != WSAEWOULDBLOCK && errsock != 0)
                        {
                            std::cout << "ERR CODE " << errsock;
                            //shutdown(SocketM[Client]);
                            closesocket(SocketM[Client]);
                            break;
                        }
                        int passdt = recv(SocketM[i],
                                            passstrings,
                                            128,
                                            0);
                        std::cout << strings << std::endl;//Log and Password in the same buff :(
                        std::cout << passstrings //nothing in buffer why?
```

I get in value string data from buffs and data from buffPass instead of only from buffs for exaple: if in Log-in edit box was "Log" and in Pass edit box- "Pass" i get LogPass
but i want seperate data from log to one string and data from pass to second. Please help me
Please help me.

Comment: If you didn't want all the data in one `recv()`, why did you request a length of 128?

Comment: is there any way to obtain my buffer length on serveer side? recv function request buffer length in third argument but how can i set it?

Comment: The sender knows the buffer length, the receiver needs it.  Two ways to do that.  Option 1 -- fixed-length message, with padding taking up the unused portion (but be careful to fill your padding with zeros or something, don't leave random data in there.  See "Heartbleed" for why that is important).  Option 2 -- send the length ahead of the data (EJP mentioned length-prefix in his answer).  In option #2, the length itself is fixed-size, so the problem doesn't recurse.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a byte-stream protocol. If you want to separate messages, it is up to you to do so, via separator characters, length-word prefixes, self-describing protocols like XML, type-length-value protocols, ...

NB it isn't valid to check `WSAGetLastError()` unless there *was* an error: i.e. in this case if `recv()` returned -1.

Comment: It's also not a good idea to call other API functions, like `Sleep`, prior to checking error codes.